# CSS hover to stay on mouse over

Tags: html, css, hover, opacity, fade

Okay, so if you could go to;

http://jsfiddle.net/aled2305/UzM7U/4/

you will see a blue circle, when you take your mouse over a red square will appear to the right. Now that all works how I want, but I would like the red box to stay when the user then takes their mouse over it.

Now if you take your mouse over where the red square shows, it will show because of

```
.down:hover
{
    opacity:100;
}
```

So is there a way to get the red square to stay when a mouse is over it, but only when it is activated by hovering over the blue circle.

Thanks in advance

Aled

**UPDATE**

Sorry forgot to say I would like the red square to hide once the mouse has been taken off.

Thanks

Comment: I definitely don't see a 'red square' in the example.

Comment: Your Fiddle has no JavaScript, and no CSS `hover` selectors - I think you missed something there...

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to update the code after editing...link updated

Comment: You will need javascript as far as I know on this. Here is a fiddle with a basic function to do this, http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/UzM7U/7/.

Comment: please all, see this link on W3C http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/opacity, specially the part => "Any values outside the range 0.0 (fully transparent) to 1.0 (fully opaque) will be clamped to this range." There is no opacity: 100

Comment: @Mark Good point! I didn't even notice that at first. You should be using 0/1 for hide/show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My demo will fade-in the **square** upon hovering the **circle**.  From there, when you hover over the **square**, it will stay opaque.  After you move off the **circle** or **square**, the **square** will fade-out.

The trick to getting this to work is setting 2 different transitions for the `opacity`, `height`, and `width` properties of the **square**, one for **hover ON** and one for **hover OFF**, as well as adding a `delay` attribute to the transition.  The reason for transitioning `height` and `width` is that it will prevent you from being able to hover over the **square** without first hovering over the **circle**.

Here are the default settings of the **square**: `opacity: 0`, `height: 0`, and `width: 0`.

For the **hover ON** transition, you want `opacity` to fade-in over 1 second, but to be able to see that, the `height` and `width` values need to be 40px prior to the fade-in transition.  To make that happen, you need to set a delay of 0 seconds on the `height` and `width` transitions.  This way, the **square** is immediately at its max dimensions, which allows the fade-in transition to be seen.

The **hover OFF** transition will revert back to the default settings.  What you want to have happen is for the `opacity` to ease-out over 1 second while at the same time keeping the values of `height` and `width` at 40px. Otherwise, `height` and `width` would instantly revert back 0 and you would not be able to see the fade-out transition. To make that happen you need to set a delay of 1 second on the `height` and `width` transitions.  In doing that, the `opacity` eases out over 1 second and because of the 1 second delay on `height` and `width`, at that point, `height` and `width` will revert back 0.

### [***See the jsFiddle demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/twa7F/)

### HTML

```
<div id="gravatar">
    <div id="circle"></div>
    <div id="square"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#gravatar
{
    float: left;
}

#circle
{
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    height: 40px; 
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#square
{
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;

    /* hover OFF */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0s 1s ease, width 0s 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0s 1s ease, width 0s 1s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0s 1s ease, width 0s 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0s 1s ease, width 0s 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0s 1s ease, width 0s 1s ease;
}

#square:hover,
#circle:hover + #square
{
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    opacity: 1;

    /* hover ON */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0 0 ease, width 0 0 ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0 0 ease, width 0 0 ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0 0 ease, width 0 0 ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0 0 ease, width 0 0 ease;
    transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0 0 ease, width 0 0 ease;
}
```

---

### EDIT

The OP left a comment stating that adding contents to the **square** prevents the transitions from working correctly.  I corrected it by adding `overflow: hidden` to the **square**.

*I also added other styles to the CSS to account for the anchors the OP added.*

### [***See the jsFiddle demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/8jqvN/)

### HTML

```
<div id="gravatar">
    <div id="circle"></div>
    <div id="square">
        <a href="http://techyoucation.com/?page_id=156">Profile Details</a> 
        <a href="http://techyoucation.com/?page_id=59">Account Details</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#gravatar
{
    float: left;
}

#circle
{
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    height: 40px; 
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#square
{
    background-color: #2D3538;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
        
    /* hover OFF */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0 1s ease, width 0 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0 1s ease, width 0 1s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0 1s ease, width 0 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0 1s ease, width 0 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0 1s ease, width 0 1s ease;
}

#square > a
{
    display: block;
    font: 15px Verdana;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#square > a:last-child
{
    margin-top: 0;
}

#square > a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#square:hover,
#circle:hover + #square
{
    height: 60px;
    width: 135px;
    opacity: 1;
    
    /* hover ON */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0 0 ease, width 0 0 ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0 0 ease, width 0 0 ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0 0 ease, width 0 0 ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0 0 ease, width 0 0 ease;
    transition: opacity 1s 0 ease-in-out, height 0 0 ease, width 0 0 ease;
}
```

Comment: 1+ .. better than the other answers.

Comment: @Scott Nearly perfect, just is there any change you can make it fade out like MathiasaurusRex ones? Thanks and sorry JoshC for replying to you instead of Scott!

Comment: @Scott Sorry I have read the post but can't get it to fade out?

Comment: @aled2305 - There you go! I got it all to work as you wanted. I've updated my answer with the full solution. Read my answer for the reasoning behind the changes.

Comment: @Scott Thanks you so much... You wouldn't believe how grateful I am. Thanks :)

Comment: @Scott Right I understand I'm probably annoying you now. But adding link's to the square makes it not work. If you hover over the circle and see where the square appears. Now bring your mouse in to where the square will appear from the right. It appears without going over the circle. See http://jsfiddle.net/aled2305/twa7F/5/

Comment: @aled2305 - The main thing you need is `overflow:hidden` on the square.  I went ahead and reworked your CSS and came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/8jqvN/.

Comment: @JoshC Absolutely amazing, got it working perfectly on my site too... Thanks So much :)

Comment: @aled2305 - You're welcome.  Glad you got it working just like you wanted!

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a Fiddle Using JS that follows the following logic:](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/UzM7U/10/)

1. Red Box shows when hovering on Blue Circle
2. Red Box hides when mouse leaves Reds

You can get that effect by adding a little JQuery and modifying your CSS:

**JQuery:**

```
$(".gravatar").hover(
  function () {
    $(".down").addClass('hoverDown');
  }
);

$(".down").mouseleave(
  function () {
    $(".down").removeClass('hoverDown');
  }
);
```

**Here's the CSS:**

```
.gravatar {
    background-color:blue;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left:  2px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px; 
}

.down
{
    float:left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color:Red;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;


    }
.hoverDown
{
    opacity:1;

}
```

Comment: This works, but I don't see where the OP mentioned he wanted jQuery.

Comment: @Scott Your right scott I was hopping to just use CSS and HTML... Is this possible?

Comment: And Sorry forgot to say I would like the red square to hide once the mouse has been taken off.

Comment: one does not simply assume that opacity 100 excists

Comment: @aled2305 Wait just a second, if you wanted the effect to go away when the mouse is off of the circle then what is the matter with the `:hover`?

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex Yeah I am a little lost now.

Comment: @aled2305 I updated my answer so that the following logic takes place: 
Red Box shows when hovering on Blue Circle,
Red Box hides when mouse leaves Red Box

Comment: Okay so in the code I uploaded. You would hover over the blue circle and the red box would show. If you hovered over where the red box WILL show it appeared. I would like you to have to hover over the blue circle, and if there was a delay before it want, you could get your mouse to the red square before it hid, so that you could click on the links that will be in it. So lie this http://jsfiddle.net/aled2305/caaxA/1/ if you could get the mouse to the red box in time it should stay (but with face in and fade out)

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex that is nearly perfect, but could you have it so that if I leave the blue circle and don't move the mouse into the red square within 3 seconds it would hide anyway? - Thanks

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex Yes but is there any way it could be `<div class="gravatar"></div>
<div class="down"></div>` instead of `<div class="gravatar">
    <div class="down"></div>
</div>` or is that not possible? (I need it to be like that) sorry :(

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex Don't worry got it. Thanks for all your work :)

Answer (score 0):

well for mouse in and mouse out action you can use the mousenter mouseleave jquery function

```
$(".gravatar").mouseenter(
  function () {
    $(".down").addClass('hoverDown');
  }
);
$(".gravatar").mouseleave(
  function () {
    $(".down").removeClass('hoverDown');
  }
);
```

working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UzM7U/9/